# Extract first three columns from all tsv files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have several tsv files in a folder which add up to over 50 gb total. To make it easier on memory when loading these files into R, I want to extract only the first 3 columns of these files.

How can all of the files have their columns extracted at once in terminal? I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }' < inputFile`

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a perfect use case for the [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) utility

You can use it as follows:

```
cut -d$"\t" -f 1-3 folder/*
```

Where `-d` specifies the field delimiter (in this case tabs), `-f` specifies the fields to extract and `folder/*` is a [glob](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) specifying all files to be parsed.

Comment: It is telling me the delimiter must be a single character.

Comment: The command should be updated to `cut -d$'\t' -f 1-3 folder/*` in order to solve that problem

Comment: @ngj Thanks for the correction ;) I didn't know that feature of bash and didn't test my original answer. Also, cut defaults to TAB as a delimiter, so the -d part isn't necessary

Comment: I was actually surprised by the error, so my previous suggestion is something I just learned as well :-)

Comment: How do I save the files with extracted columns, overwriting the original files?

Comment: That is a bit more involved: Since the input and output file cannot be equivalent, you will probably have to do this on a file-to-file basis. Something like `for f in folder/*; do cut -d$"\t" -f 1-3 $f > ${f}.tmp; mv ${f}.tmp $f; done;` EDIT: I just saw that ngj's answer is basically this idea, so have a look over there ;)

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
    # Do something for each file. In our case, just echo the first three fields:
    cut -f1-3 < "$f"
done
```

(See [this webpage](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) for more info on iterating over files in bash.)

The answer by M. Becerra contains a one-liner in which the same can be achieved using the [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command. My own answer can thus be considered more complicated than necessary, unless you want to do additional processing for each file (e.g., construct some statistics while iterating over the files).

**EDIT:** If you want to overwrite the actual files, you can use something like the following script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
    # Do something for each file. In our case, echo the first three fields to a new file, and rename the new file to the original file:
    cut -f1-3 < "$f" > "$f.tmp"
    rm "$f"
    mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
done
```

The `cut` line writes its output to the original filename with `.tmp` appended; the following two lines remove the original file and rename the new file to the original filename.

Comment: How do I save the files with extracted columns, overwriting the original files?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. I tested it on my own machine, but make sure you test it on yours and have the appropriate backups of your original files!

Comment: I ran into a problem that is specific to my dataset, but I would appreciate if you could help guide me with this. Some of the values are blank in the second column, but after doing it the above way, it shifted the columns for those rows which didn't have a value in the second column. Is there a way to fix that and make sure that a blank spot is there in the final output? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the code examples accordingly: this was a consequence of using `awk`, and is solved by using `cut` instead as indicated.

Answer (score 4):

Do it directly in R--this will save time, disk space, and code:

```
fread("foo.tsv", sep = "\t", select=c("f1", "f2", "f3"))
```

Comment: I do not have 50 gb of ram to be able to read it all into memory in R.

Comment: The above code will only read the three columns you've asked for.  If you can't read those into memory, I'm not sure how `awk` is going to help you get them into memory.

Comment: Ohhh, okay. Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
find ./ -type f -name ".tsv" -exec awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }' {} \;
```

You can run it from the directory where you have the files, or just add the absolute path instead.

If you want to have it saved into a file you can redirect the output of `awk`:

```
find ./ -type f -name ".tsv" -exec awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }' {} >> someOtherFile \;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this directly in R, depending on what packages are installed. These methods all keep memory use to a minimum.

With the base (default) package (creates a `data.frame`):

```
> df1 = read.table(pipe("cut -f 1-3 *.tsv"), sep="\t", header=FALSE, quote="")
```

Using the `tidyverse/readr` package (creates a `tibble`):

```
> df2 = read_tsv(pipe("cut -f 1-3 *.tsv"))
```

Using `data.table`(creates a `data.table`, or optionally, a `data.frame`):

```
> df3 = fread("cut -f 1-3 *.tsv")
```

Each of these techniques invokes a unix shell command, reading the output of the command. This minimizes memory use. An arbitrary shell pipeline can be used, so other commands can be combined. For example, to get a random set of 10,000 lines:

```
> df4 = fread("cut -f 1,3 *.tsv | shuf -n 10000")
```

Each of these methods has a full array of options for customizing the input process.